# Getting Value Error from CoolProp mixture

Tags: python, mixture

I'm new with CoolProp and I'm trying to get values(density, entalpy ect) from mixture of gases.
When I use this code it is working fine:

`i_2 = PropsSI('H', 'T', 340, 'P', 101325, 'HEOS::O2[0.07]&CO2[0.12]&Ar[0.006]&Water[0.1]&N2[0.7]')`

`i_2 = 523080.7286096605`

But when I use higher temperature I get a this error.

`ValueError: One stationary point (not good) for T=345,p=101325,z=[ 0.0801159090456, 0.0211270074909, 0.00654417174276, 4.32846575225e-05, 0.892169627063 ] : PropsSI("H","T",345,"P",101325,"HEOS::O2[0.07]&CO2[0.12]&Ar[0.006]&Water[0.1]&N2[0.7]")`

Do I have to use more points or give it more data?

Thank you in advance